# CSS: Preventing one div from wrapping beneath another

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent one div from wrapping beneath another? Specifically, I want the 2nd div to always be to the right of the 1st div, even if the browser width is resized such that the 2nd div's contents must wrap.

I always want the divs to be side by side: 
[image: I want this the divs to always be side by side]

and to never look like this, even if the browser window is resized such that the 2nd div's contents must wrap:
[image: And never have the 2nd div wrap beneath the first div]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="columns">
      <div style="background-color: #990000; width:70px; float: left">
        Pic
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #00FF00; float: left; " >
      body some interesting large amount of content. some interesting large amount of content.
      </div>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<div class="columns">
  <div style="background-color: #990000; width:70px; float: left">
      Pic
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #00FF00; margin-left: 70px;" >
      body some interesting large amount of content. some interesting large amount of content.
  </div>    
</div>
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/arPzt/